# Scala: Convert Json JObject to List

Tags: scala, json4s

I have this sample URL: https://api.github.com/repos/jdan/isomer/languages
The difference in output here is that its not normally how we expect JSON to be i.e. "label": "value". It is "Language_Name":"Number of lines".

When i call this api from my scala code:

```
val responseLangUrl: HttpResponse[String] = Http(url").asString
val responseLangUrlJson = parse(responseLangUrl.body)
println(responseLangUrlJson)
```

Output is:

```
JObject(List((Ruby,JInt(2622))))
JObject(List((CoffeeScript,JInt(3513)), (JavaScript,JInt(380))))
```

JInt is insignificant to me. I want list of all these language names. How can i extract that?

https://github.com/json4s/json4s: This official link has example for "label":"value"case but how i extract something like this i.e. type of JSON where i directly have information.

Answer (score 3):

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

parse("""
 {
   "JavaScript": 54179,
   "CSS": 508,
   "HTML": 406
}
""").foldField(List(): List[String])((l, t) => t._1 :: l)
```

results in

```
res0: List[String] = List(HTML, CSS, JavaScript)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way IMO, is to convert JSON into `Map[String, Any]` and then extract the keys.

```
parse("""
 {
   "JavaScript": 54179,
   "CSS": 508,
   "HTML": 406
}
""").extract[Map[String, Any]].map(_._1)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List(JavaScript, CSS, HTML)
```

Comment: val response:HttpResponse[String]=Http(url).asString;

val responseJson = parse(responseLangUrl.body);

This responseJson does not have extract method. Any idea?

Comment: You need to bring `DefaultFormats` into scope. https://github.com/json4s/json4s#extracting-values